# Unit of measure the php opcache.revalidate_freq setting

Tags: php, opcache

When opcache.revalidate_freq=2, does it mean the scripts timestamps are checked for update:

- twice per second?
- or every other second?

The name of the setting containing "frequency" let me believe it is the former.

But the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.revalidate-freq) and most of the resources I find online let one think the unit of measure of this setting is not a frequency, but a duration in seconds.

So which one is it?

Comment: The docs say "How often to check script timestamps for updates, **in seconds**."

Comment: So if a PHP file is cached at 13:00:05 and you request it again at 13:00:06 then it will not check for a fresh file even if the file's timestamp is later than 13:00:05. If you request it again at 13:00:08 then it check for a fresh file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description says "How often ... in seconds". This means that it's the number of seconds between checks, so setting it to `2` means every other second.

If they meant twice per second it would say something like "per second" or "in Hertz".

Comment: So you agree that the name of the setting, `revalidate_freq` is misleading right?

Comment: Not really. It's very common to describe frequency as "every N time-periods", not only "N per time-period". This is technically the wavelength, but these aren't really waves.